# How to convert a string into an array?

Tags: javascript

How do I convert the following string to an array?

String:

```
var string = "[energy,people,coding,vein]";
```

Array:

```
var array = ["energy","people","coding","vein"];
```

Comment: did you try to solve it yourself? If so, what was your code?

Comment: Here's the general logic for one approach: 1. Strip the `[` and `]` from the string, 2. Split the new string by `,`. Now try out some code and let us know how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to convert a string of comma separated values into an array is just to use split.

```
string1 = "testing,stuff";
arr = string1.split(","); // arr now equals ["testing", "stuff"]
```

The opening and closing brackets you could just get rid of using the substr method, or just leaving them off initially if you have that option

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer "The opening and closing brackets you could just get rid of using the substr method, or just leaving them off initially if you have that option"

Answer (score 0):

This is a two part process:

1. Remove the brackets with `String.substr()` (assuming the first and last characters in your string are brackets).
2. Use `String.split()` to break the string into an array.

This is the most efficient way to convert the string '[energy,people,coding,vein]' into an array:

```
var String1 = '[energy,people,coding,vein]',
    array = String1.substr(1, String1.length - 2).split(',');

console.log(array); // ["energy", "people", "coding", "vein"]
```